# Getting error while running the mysql query to create table

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting one error while creating table using MySQL. I am explaining my query below.

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE db_cron( ".
        "id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ".
        "user_alert INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT NONE, ".
        "status INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT NONE, ".
        "PRIMARY KEY ( id )); ";
```

I am getting the below error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'NONE, status INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT NONE, PRIMARY KEY ( id ))'
>   at line 1

Here I need to create table with default value as none.

Comment: Requiring `NOT NULL` but  `DEFAULT NONE`, hmmm

Comment: error message seems clear to me

Comment: subhra  check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You have applied unnecessary quotes.

2.You have `NOT NULL` along with `DEFAULT NONE`, which is not going to happen(You have to provide some value as default when using `NOT NULL`)

Do like below:-

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE db_cron(
        id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        user_alert INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        status INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        PRIMARY KEY ( id )
    )";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used too many quotes just to connect multiple string, it does not required.

Please remove those quotes and you also have to provide default value instead of `NULL` something like `0` OR any other value that you want.

However you can use below query to create table.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `db_cron`( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                   user_alert INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
                   status INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
                   PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";
```

above query will create table with default value `0` for `user_alert` and `status`

Hope this will helps you

Thanks & Regards.